# Using eventlistener in reactjs(JSX)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn Reactjs  but I am not able to work it out. 
I want to add sticky header class to my table which is rendered using Reactjs but I am not getting any success with this code/pseudocode.

```
handleScroll: function(e){
  var header = this.root.querySelector('.header');
var origOffsetY = header.offsetTop;
  window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? header.addClass('sticky'): header.removeClass('sticky');
},

componentDidMount : function(){
window.addEventListener('handleScroll',this.handleScroll);
},
```

I am trying to use this Javascript function:

```
<script>
var header = document.querySelector('.header');
var origOffsetY = header.offsetTop;

function onScroll(e) {
  window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? header.classList.add('sticky') :
                                  header.classList.remove('sticky');
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
</script>
```

But I am not getting any success. Is there any easier way to implement javascript function in Reactjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
window.addEventListener('handleScroll', this.handleScroll);
```

I'm guessing you meant instead:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
```

Comment: Yes and I am also seeing this error in the console:
Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined.

Comment: What is `this.root`? It's not defined when you are trying to access it in `handleScroll`.

Comment: I am seeing this error while I scroll down so I think the function is triggered during scroll but I may have to figure out this object. Must be some syntax error. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry to bother you all but all I had to do was roll the vanilla JS function 


/****************************/
handleScroll: function(e){
 var header = document.querySelector('.header');
var origOffsetY = header.offsetTop;
 window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? header.classList.add('sticky') :
                                  header.classList.remove('sticky');
},

componentDidMount : function(){
window.addEventListener('scroll',this.handleScroll);
},
/**********************/